# How to define DateTime parse format for general date format with optional time part?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datetime-format

What is the right `DateTime` format to parse a date from string in general date format `("G")` with optional time part `("d")`?

I can have two types of dates:

1. `"12/13/2012 6:30:00 PM"`
2. `"3/29/2013"`

How to parse them in unified way?
Right now I'm trying to parse with `"G"` format and then if it not parsed with `"d"` format.

Comment: What is your `CurrentCulture`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) supports `MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt` (I assume your [`LongTimePattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.longtimepattern%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has `h`) and `M/dd/yyyy` (I assume your [`ShortDatePattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shortdatepattern%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has `M`) as standard date and time format, using [`DateTime.TryParse(String, out DateTime)` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can solve all your problems.

```
string s = "";
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParse(s, out dt))
{
    // Your string parsed successfully.
}
```

If these formats doesn't standard date and time format for your `CurrentCulture`, using [`DateTime.TryParseExact(String, String[], IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles, DateTime)` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can be the best choice because it takes formats part as a string array. That means, you can provide multiple formats and your string will be parsed with first successful match.

```
string s = "";
string[] formats = { "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", "M/dd/yyyy" };
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(s, formats, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                           DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    // Your string parsed with one of speficied format.
}
```

Be careful when you parse string that have [`"/"` custom format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator). It has a special meaning of *replace me with current culture or specified culture date separator*. That means if your `CurrentCulture`'s [`DateSeparator` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator.aspx) is not `/`, your parsing operation will fail *even* if your string and formats are the same format.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `DateTime.Parse()` or if you want to do a safe parse attempt `DateTime.TryParse()`

```
DateTime dt1, dt2;
dt1 = DateTime.Parse("12/13/2012 6:30:00 PM");
dt2 = DateTime.Parse("3/29/2013");
```

OR

```
DateTime.TryParse("12/13/2012 6:30:00 PM", out dt1);
DateTime.TryParse("3/29/2013", out dt2);
```

You only have to use `DateTime.ParseExact()` or provide the format if it differs from the accepted formats that `DateTime.Parse()` accepts, or if you only allow one particular format.

Comment: with two attempts to parse - it is an easy task. No way to do in one parse request?

Comment: @DreamTeamMobile: What do you mean exactly by "one parse request"? One obvious simplification would be to create a tiny method containing the two TryParse() calls. Another possibility would be a chained set of "if" statements.

Comment: You just need one line. Assign your string to a variable and use DateTime.Parse, i was just showing that both formats work with DateTime.Parse