# Parse year/month/day string with unknown dividers and optional time element into a DateTime, in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing, date-parsing

I have to parse date string in C#. The dates are all ensured to start with year, month, day. But I do not know what dividers will be between the 3 parts.
Additionally the date string may also include a time part after the date.

Basically as long as the format has the year first, month second, and day third, I should parse it as a valid date regardless of which dividers are used and whether a time is included. Any other date formats should be rejected as invalid.

I can not figure out how to do this without writing a long if/else.

**How do I parse a string into a C# datetime object, given the restrictions mentioned?**

Comment: Do you know in which language each given date is? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26140560/1997232), it's for optional time, but you could try to use same approach instead of many if/else.

Comment: Thanks, it would indeed be a lot better to give an array of formats rather than write a lot of if/else. However, there are still quite a few options, so I was hoping for something a bit more elegant.

Comment: Do you consider using `Regex` to parse `string` into `DateTime`? It is pretty easy if you know format of the `string`?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the length of the input string is at least 10 characters, and if it is, work out what the separator should be by looking at the 5th character in the string.

Then you can use the separator to construct a format string that you pass to `DateTime.TryParseExact()` to parse the date. You also have to truncate the date string to 10 characters to ignore any date part at the end.

An example implementation looks like this - it returns null if the date didn't parse; otherwise, it returns the correctly parsed date:

```
public static DateTime? ParseDateWithUnknownDivider(string dateStr)
{
    if (dateStr.Length < 10)
        return null;

    char divider = dateStr[4];

    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(
        dateStr.Substring(0, 10), 
        $"yyyy\\{divider}MM\\{divider}dd",
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        DateTimeStyles.None, 
        out DateTime result))
            return result;

    return null;
}
```

Note that this ignores the time part and will always return the time part as 00:00:00. If that's not what you meant, you will need to specify in your question what the time part would look like. For example, would it be separated from the date part by a space? And would it always be hh:mm:ss? And would it be 24hour clock?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
string yourDateTimeString = ....;
string format="yyyy/MM/dd";
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(yourDateTimeString,format,null,System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
```